# Display a List in a DIV with Ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use ajax to display a list of strings in a div but I am not sure how to parse the data in Ajax.

Here is my method in C#:

```
public JsonResult GetRecentEmployeeRecords(string whse)
{
    var recentRecords = _employeeDb.EmployeeMasters.Where(e => e.Branch == whse).OrderBy(e => e.CreateDate).Take(10);
    var list = recentRecords.Select(r => r.EmployeeNumber + " - " + r.LastName + ", " + r.FirstName).ToList();
    var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(list);
    return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is my ajax statement:

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../Employee/GetRecentEmployeeRecords',
        data:
        {
            whse: $('#Branch').val(),
        },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i in data) {
                $('#recentEmployeeNumbers').val(data[i] + "<br/>");
                alert(data[i]);
            }
        }
    });
```

and it appears that I am getting data back but it appears as it is only giving me single characters at a time. What is the best way to get the entire string at a time and display all ten of them in a div?

Comment: please show what's coming into success function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are double JSON encoding the response.

The `return Json(..)` will encode the result but you have already encoded it in your call to `jsonSerialiser.Serialize`. From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504936(v=vs.118).aspx) documentation the `Controller.Json` method:

> Creates a JsonResult object that serializes the specified object to JavaScript Object Notation (JSON).

To solve it simply pass `list` directly to the `Json` call:

```
public JsonResult GetRecentEmployeeRecords(string whse)
{
    var recentRecords = _employeeDb.EmployeeMasters.Where(e => e.Branch == whse).OrderBy(e => e.CreateDate).Take(10);
    var list = recentRecords.Select(r => r.EmployeeNumber + " - " + r.LastName + ", " + r.FirstName).ToList();

    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Also, in your JavaScript you are then overwriting the contents of the `div` on each iteration:

```
$('#recentEmployeeNumbers').val(data[i] + "<br/>");
```

You could swap the `val` for `append` to append the details to the `div`:

```
$('#recentEmployeeNumbers').append(data[i] + "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 2):

I see <strike>two</strike> *three* issues.  First, it looks like you are double encoding your response in your c# code.  `JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize()` and `Json()` do more or less the same thing.  Pick one.

Second, in JavaScript, `for..in` is for enumerating an Object.  It looks like you want to iterate an array.  For that, use a regular `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('#recentEmployeeNumbers').val(data[i] + "<br/>");
    alert(data[i]);
}
```

An easier way to iterate an array is with jQuery's `$.each()`:

```
$.each(data, function(i) {
    $('#recentEmployeeNumbers').val(this + "<br/>");
    alert(this);
});
```

Or, JavaScript 5's `Array.forEach()`:

```
data.forEach(function(item, i) {
    $('#recentEmployeeNumbers').val(item + "<br/>");
    alert(item);
});
```

Use an [`Array.forEach()` polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill) for older browsers.

**Edit:** Third, you are replacing the value of `#recentEmployeeNumbers` in each iteration of the loop.  `.val()` is only good for input elements, but you asked about populating a div.  You want something like `.append()` (for html) or `.text()` (will html encode values):

```
$.each(data, function(i) {
    $("<div>").text(this).appendTo('#recentEmployeeNumbers');
});
```

One more small thing I noticed.  You don't really need to call `.ToList()`.  Either JSON serializer should be able to handle serializing an `IEnumerable<string>` without a problem.